# how to create link to systemd via ansible

Tags: linux, ansible

I deliver a systemd unit file to a remote host via ansible to the directory `/my_folder` and then create links to it.

Is there any best practice method to create these?

I'm using this task:

```
shell: systemctl link /my_folder/my_unit.service
```

Comment: A reasonable person might wonder why you don't just put the file in any of the predefined unit search path such that `- systemd: name=my_unit enabled=yes` will do the right thing; that said, the hardest part about your question is making it idempotent -- where does the symlink end up such that you could guard that task with `args: creates: /.../my_unit.service`?

Comment: there are some security reasons not to put into predefined unit directory. thank for args:create advice!